# Find which directories each group can access

Tags: permissions, directory, group

I need to take the /etc/group file (RHEL) and check what high level subdirectories each group has access to.

Here is a made up example:

```
Group 100 - \xxx\xxx\xxx
Group 150 - \xx\xxxxx\x
```

**Is that possible to know in someway?
Or perhaps using another workaround rather than /etc/group file?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find command

```
man find
```

specifically

```
       -gid n File’s numeric group ID is n.
```

Comment: This finds the directories that belong to a given group. There's far more to the question than that.